# Where did Ronan Dex get his pistol?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

Throughout the Stargate Altantis series, the badest-ass weapon on screen was arguably Ronan's powerful gun.

[image: Ronan wielding his pistol]

Where and how did Ronan get his iconic pistol?

Comment: The short answer is no-one knows;  http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Particle_magnum

Comment: http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/File:Particle_magnum_concept.jpg

Comment: http://www.gateworld.net/wiki/Ronon's_gun

Comment: Chekhov lent it to him, on the condition that he **really** fires it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While we never find out the backstory of HOW Ronan got his Particle Magnum, we do know that it is a standard sidearm of the Travellers and is manufactured by them. The most likely scenario is that some point after he was released as a runner, he by chance came across some travellers during one of the incredibly rare occurrences where they land in order to gather more supplies.

Scenario 1: Shortly after he meets the Travellers, the Wraith show up, attacking them. The Travellers throw him a Particle Magnum to defend himself with, and after they kill the hunting party, the Travellers allow Ronan to keep the Magnum when they part ways.

Scenario 2: The Travellers associate him with the Wraith, being a runner, and start an altercation. Ronan defends himself, knocking out/killing the Travellers. He helps himself to the spoils, including a Particle Magnum.

I find it's best that we don't have a proper backstory for that particular weapon. That way, everyone can come up with their own ideas, much like the Joker's scars. Personally I like scenario 1. It seems the most likely and paints Ronan is a positive light. He also gets to kill Wraith.

Comment: Or, y'know, he bought it at a shop.

Comment: I'm not sure he would just "buy it". I think he would offer a deal that is fair. And if you said it wasn't, he'd say it is.